# Object doesn't support property or method 'kendoTabStrip'

Tags: kendo-ui

I have the following jQuery code in my js file:

```
$(document).bind('ready', function () {

  $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
     animation: {
        open: {
           effects: "fadeIn"
        }
     }
  });
)};
```

When I try to load this js file, I am getting the following error:

```
0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'kendoTabStrip'
```

Included these CSS files

```
@Html.Css(Url.Content("~/Assets/CSS/Kendo/kendo.common.min.css"))
@Html.Css(Url.Content("~/Assets/CSS/Kendo/kendo.default.min.css"))
```

Can any one help in getting out of this error?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

This means that either the Kendo UI JavaScript files are not included or jQuery is included more than once. More info is available here: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/troubleshooting#javascript-error-that-kendo-widgets-are-unavailable-or-undefined